# How do I convert an IEnumerable<Task<string>> into an IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, async-await

Really simplified example to try and focus the question, so please bear with me.

Suppose I have a collection of `string`s that are Ids for some objects. I want to check they exist in my database.

If I do the following...

```cs
var results = new List<string> { "123456", "654321" }
.Select(async s => {
  // Check the database
  return "The result";
});
```

...then I get an `IEnumerable<Task<string>>`, whereas I want an `IEnumerable<string>`.

I can't work out where the `Task` is coming from, as the lambda returns a `string`. I see that if I remove the `async` modifier from the lambda, then I get an `IEnumerable<string>`, but then I can't `await` my database call inside the lambda.

Anyone able to explain to me why I get an `IEnumerable<Task<string>>`, and how I should write this code so I get an `IEnumerable<string>` instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is coming from the async/await call. All these results are wrapped in `Task<T>`

This means you need to await all the tasks

```cs
var results = await Task.WhenAll(new List<string> { "123456", "654321" }
    .Select(async s => {
      // Check the database
      return "The result";
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Will this have any performance problems if the collection is large?

Comment: The return type is an array, so it will bring the collection into memory

Comment: Well, yes. Since you're calling the database for every single id it's not likely to scale well. But that does not have anything to do with the code being asynchronous. Consider checking the database for multiple ids instead of a single one.